# Rails: create or update in model saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model (Bookmark) with two fields, call them A and B.
When creating a new model i have to perform a rather complex check on B and, if `true` update a Bookmark in the database (setting A to the one being passed) and abort the creation, if `false` just keep it on and create a new Bookmark.

So I set a before_create filter. The problem with the function called is that if I perform an update_attributes on a retrieved object from it and then return false (in order to abort the saving), the update is not performed (for some reason I don't know).

update_attributes returns true and there are no errors, but in the log i only see

```
SQL (0.2ms)
```

If i don't return false, the record is correctly updated, but it also inserts a new record (and I don't want this). Any help?

Comment: Returning false in an AR callback will, by design, abort the entire transaction.  Is that what is happening here?

Comment: yes, think. any way to work this around?

Comment: would an observer be more appropriate for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Canceling callbacks**

If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: hi, thanks for the clarification. are you saying that i cannot solve my problem in this way?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post your before_create code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

When using callbacks, any call to `update_attribute` from within the `before_create` callback will bork it.

I was bitten unexpectedly by this as well.  I think the source for this came from the rails api, in a one liner, or a blog post that escapes me right now, sorry.

This complicated call isn't a validation though?

Or maybe you can pull out the update_attribute and use it after the complicated logic?

Comment: hi. ho, the call is not a validation. if i could performa the update from within the validation, it, wouldn't it be arrested anyway?